# Different predictions when running Keras model in TensorFlow Lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

Trying out TensorFlow Lite with a pretrained Keras image classifier, I'm getting worse predictions after converting the H5 to the tflite format. Is this intended behaviour (e.g. weight quantization), a bug or am I forgetting something when using the interpreter?

## Example

```
from imagesoup import ImageSoup
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

# Load an example image.
ImageSoup().search('terrier', n_images=1)[0].to_file('image.jpg')
i = load_img('image.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
x = img_to_array(i)
x = x[None, ...]
x = preprocess_input(x)

# Classify image with Keras.
model = ResNet50()
y = model.predict(x)
print("Keras:", decode_predictions(y))

# Convert Keras model to TensorFlow Lite.
model.save(f'{model.name}.h5')
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TocoConverter.from_keras_model_file
tflite_model = converter(f'{model.name}.h5').convert()
with open(f'{model.name}.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)

# Classify image with TensorFlow Lite.
f = tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter(f'{model.name}.tflite')
f.allocate_tensors()
i = f.get_input_details()[0]
o = f.get_output_details()[0]
f.set_tensor(i['index'], x)
f.invoke()
y = f.get_tensor(o['index'])
print("TensorFlow Lite:", decode_predictions(y))
```

> Keras: [[('n02098105', 'soft-coated_wheaten_terrier', 0.70274395),
>   ('n02091635', 'otterhound', 0.0885325), ('n02090721',
>   'Irish_wolfhound', 0.06422518), ('n02093991', 'Irish_terrier',
>   0.040120784), ('n02111500', 'Great_Pyrenees', 0.03408164)]]
>
> TensorFlow Lite: [[('n07753275', 'pineapple', 0.94529104), ('n03379051',
>   'football_helmet', 0.033994876), ('n03891332', 'parking_meter',
>   0.011431991), ('n04522168', 'vase', 0.0029440755), ('n02094114', 'Norfolk_terrier', 0.0022089847)]]

Comment: There was a bug in `from_keras_model_file` in 1.10. Can you try running it with the tf-nightly release (`pip install tf-nightly`)?

Comment: Cool. Seems to be working as expected now as of 1.11.0.dev20180825. What was the bug? Is there an issue I can link to in the accepted answer?

Comment: With that said, class scores still differ slightly but at least the ranking is now the same.

Comment: I added an answer with the commit attached. Feel free to use it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in `from_keras_model_file` in TensorFlow 1.10. It was fixed in the August 9th nightly release in [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/37bfe7a9f290c267ff7a804038fb6c8979975dee).

The nightly can be installed via `pip install tf-nightly`. Additionally, it will be fixed in TensorFlow 1.11.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to set the learning phase to 0 in order to avoid Dropout and other non-deterministic layers during the prediction phase?

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/learning_phase

Comment: Yeah, `K.set_learning_phase(0)` makes no difference. The Keras model gets the classification right and the tflite model gets it wrong.